# CALayer not displaying

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-animation

So this is my first ever attempt at using a CALayer. Build is successful and no reported bugs, so I assume I must be doing something obviously wrong. But the layer does not display at all.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    // Get Reliant Magenta in amazingly verbose manner
    CGColorSpaceRef rgbaColorSpace      = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGFloat reliantMagentaValues[4]     = {(208/255),(27/255),(124/255),0.3f};
    CGColorRef reliantMagenta           = CGColorCreate(rgbaColorSpace, reliantMagentaValues);

    CALayer *reliantCanvasLayer         = [CALayer layer];

    reliantCanvasLayer.backgroundColor  = reliantMagenta;
    reliantCanvasLayer.frame            = CGRectMake(0, 0, 640, 960);

    [super viewDidLoad];

    [[[self view] layer] addSublayer:reliantCanvasLayer];

    CGColorRelease(reliantMagenta);

}
```

Instead of a full page of magenta, I get back an empty view of grey. How am I messing up something this simple?

---

UPDATE

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Get Reliant Magenta in amazingly verbose manner
    CGColorSpaceRef rgbaColorSpace      = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGFloat reliantMagentaValues[4]     = {(208/255),(27/255),(124/255),0.3f};
    CGColorRef reliantMagenta           = CGColorCreate(rgbaColorSpace, reliantMagentaValues);

    [[self view] layer].backgroundColor   = reliantMagenta;

    CGColorRelease(reliantMagenta);

}
```

same problem, but view is now black and not displaying elements added in the storyboard

Comment: What happens if you addSubLayer before super viewDidLoad?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One problem (possibly the only problem) is that you're creating your color with all zero components.  When you say `208/255`, the compiler performs the division using integers and drops the remainder, so `208/255` is 0.  You need to divide in floating point: `208.0f / 255.0f`.

It's also much easier to use a `UIColor` instead of setting up the `CGColorSpace` and the `CGColor` yourself.  Try this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIColor *reliantMagenta = [UIColor colorWithRed:208.0f / 255.0f
        green:27.0f / 255.0f blue:124.0f / 255.0f alpha:0.3f];

    CALayer *magentaLayer = [CALayer layer];
    magentaLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 640, 960);
    magentaLayer.backgroundColor = reliantMagenta.CGColor;

    [self.view.layer addSublayer:magentaLayer];
}
```

Comment: As you can tell I am new to strongly typed languages. Thanks again, this you point about floats worked perfect.

Answer (score 1):

You're adding a layer as a sublayer of itself. `[self layer]` returns the view's **existing** layer. If you want to create a separate layer, you have to do it manually. There's probably something in the view system that keeps circular references from iterating out of control.

As a point of reference, you should make it a habit of calling `[super viewDidLoad]` before you do anything else. And an easier way of creating a `CGColor` is to create a `UIColor` and get its `CGColor` property.

Comment: So how would I write that differently? Can I set the properties of the view's root layer? And I was actually trying to manually add my own sublayer.

Comment: I'm assuming you've imported <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h> and linked against QuartzCore.framework. And what Rob said.

Comment: Yeah, I did. Like I said, build successful and all.