# CALayer doesn't display

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, calayer, nsview

(I already read this page, but it didn't help me [CALayer not displaying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12656861/calayer-not-displaying))

I have a class called `Image` that has this field data:

```
uint8_t *data;
```

I already use this `data` to display this `Image` on a `CALayer` that I got gathering code from the internet.

I saw how to create another windows in my application, and I put a `NSView` inside it to display an `Image` using the method, I intend to display the histogram latter, but now I'm just trying to display again the same image:

```
-(void)wrapImageToCALayer: (CALayer*) layer{
    if(!layer) return;

    CGColorSpaceRef grayColorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray();

    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(data, width, height, 8, step, grayColorSpace, kCGImageAlphaNone);

    CGImageRef dstImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);


    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        layer.contents = (__bridge id)dstImage;
    });

    CGImageRelease(dstImage);
    CGContextRelease(context);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(grayColorSpace);
}
```

And this is my Window Controler:

```
@implementation HistogramControllerWindowController

@synthesize display;

- (id)initWithWindow:(NSWindow *)window{
    self = [super initWithWindow:window];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code here.

    }
    return self;
}

- (void)windowDidLoad
{
    // Implement this method to handle any initialization after your window controller's window has been loaded from its nib file.

    [super windowDidLoad];


    histogramDisplayLayer = [CALayer layer];
    [histogramDisplayLayer setContentsGravity:AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill];
    histogramDisplayLayer.position = CGPointMake(display.frame.size.width/2., display.frame.size.height/2.);
    [histogramDisplayLayer setNeedsDisplay];
    [display.layer addSublayer: histogramDisplayLayer];



}

@end
```

And I'm calling this way:

```
[frame wrapImageToCALayer:histogramDisplayLayer];
```

Note that `histogramDisplayLayer` is an external `(CALayer *)`

Comment: Showing code without bothering to explain variables is one thing.  Adding a layer to a layer is another thing.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get it. Are you saying that I shouldn't do this??
[display.layer addSublayer: histogramDisplayLayer];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just insert:

```
[display setWantsLayer:YES]; // view's backing store is using a Core Animation Layer
```

Before:

```
[display.layer addSublayer: histogramDisplayLayer];
```

[ [Best way to change the background color for an NSView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2962790/best-way-to-change-the-background-color-for-an-nsview) ]

Answer (score 2):

Your histogramDisplayLayer have no size defined, you just set a position but not its size. So init its frame, and this should fix your problem.